# If I use the run.Mi / sem.MI function of the semTools package. How do I get the p-values to the corresponding R^2?

Tags: r, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

If I specify:

```
dataList <- parcelAllocation(mod5555_parcel, df, parcel.names, mod5555, nAlloc = 10000, iseed = 12345, do.fit = FALSE)


fit.parcels5555 <- sem.mi(mod5555_parcel, data = dataList)
summary(fit.parcels5555, fit.measures = TRUE, standardized = TRUE, rsq = TRUE)
```

... I get the R^2 values but no associated significance p-values.

How can I get these?

Comment: Can you please tell us what packages these functions come from, and if possible please provide a reproducible example with data and code so that we can test it out?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have changed it as requested.

Comment: Thanks for the edits but this still does not say what packages are used (what `library()` was called)

Comment: You can read about providing a reprex here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  But an R-squared is not a parameter, so it doesn't not have a *p* value.  That has nothing to do with using multiple-imputation methods.  If you analyze a single data set with `lavaan::sem()`, you will also not get *p* values for R-squared.